# Is it possible to write a recursive IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, collections, recursion, ienumerable

I have a class like:

```
class Spline
    int ChildrenCount;
    Spline GetChild (int index)

class SplineCollection : IEnumerable<Spline>
    Spline Master
```

Is it possible to write a recursive IEnumerable for the SplineCollection where it will return all the children one by one?

EDIT: So Master is the root Box, and the hierarchy of its children can be any depth.

EDIT: By using the name Box, I think I confused some people. It's meant to be a geometric object, not a container. So changing it to Spline.

Comment: I take it you mean "descendants" when you write "children", as getting the children requires no recursion.

Comment: @Job, Yes you are right I meant descendants. It's just that in the sdk I am using, they are still referred to as Children, ChildrenRecursive, so that's why I just used that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do a depth-first traversal of the `Box` 'tree'. You can then just call this method on the `Master` box to return all the recursive children.

```
public class Box
{
    // ...

    public IEnumerable<Box> GetBoxes() 
    {
        yield return this;

        for (int i=0; i<box.ChildrenCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (Box child in box.GetChild(i).GetBoxes())
            {
                 yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but will this go through the Children of each box.GetChild(i) too?

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 13):

I would go with manually maintaining a stack instead of relying on the call stack here. The reason is because a new `IEnumerable<Spline>` would have to be created for each `Spline` visited if you used the call stack by recursively calling the method that gets the descendants. That would be inefficient. You can significantly improve the traversal by using your own stack.

```
public IEnumerable<Spline> Descendants
{
    get
    {
        // This performs a simple iterative preorder traversal.
        var stack = new Stack<Spline>(new Spline[] { this });
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            Spline current = stack.Pop();
            yield return current;
            for (int i = current.ChildrenCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                stack.Push(current.GetChild(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could vote this up 10 times.  This is *so* much more efficient than a recursive solution, and only requires a few seconds more thought.  In fact, you could generalize this into a `Flatten` function to simplify any recursive iterator.

Comment: This actually also returns the root element, not only the actual descendants.

Answer (score 3):

Yep - see this section for [Recursive Iterations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163682.aspx#S3) using C# iterators.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Box
{
  int ChildrenCount;
  Box GetChild (int index){/* some implementation*/}
  public IEnumerable<Box> Children
  {
    get
    {
      for(int i = 0; i != ChildrenCount; ++i)
        yield return GetChild(i);
    }
  }
  public IEnumerable<Box> Descendants
  {
    get
    {
      foreach(Box child in Children)
      {
        yield return child;
        foreach(Box desc in child.Descendants)
          yield return desc;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can call this from BoxCollection, but since Box is already a collection of Boxes, I don't see what BoxCollection's purpose is here. For that matter, having Box implement `IEnumerable<Box>` or one of its descendants (`ICollection<Box>`, `IList<Box>`) would probably improve usefulness.

It's also possible to do it in an iterative rather than recursive manner, which sometimes has a better performance (pretty much any time that the compiler doesn't turn the recursion into interation anyway), but recursive is more readable and normally more than performant enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to enumerate the recursive result. You can't just yield return it, because the type doesn't match.

```
IEnumerable<int> Triangle(int n) {
    yield return n;
    if (n > 0)
        foreach (var e in Triangle(n - 1))
            yield return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds to the great answer by Brian Gideon, providing really only the descendants, without the root element. It furthermore uses `foreach`, which may be available for example in EF contexts.

Here's my code ():

```
/// <summary>
///     Retrieves all descendants.
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<Item> Descendants {
    get {
        // This performs a simple iterative preorder traversal.
        Stack<Item> stack = new Stack<Item>(this.Children);
        while (stack.Count > 0) {
            Itemcurrent = stack.Pop();
            yield return current;

            //Push current's children
            foreach (Item currentChild in current.Children) {
                stack.Push(currentChild);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure. You don't even really need a BoxContainer, since box, by its name, exists as a container:

```
public class Box
{
    private List<Box> myBoxes;

    public IEnumerable<Box> GetAllBoxes()
    {
        yield return this;
        foreach (var box in myBoxes)
        {
            var enumerator = box.GetAllBoxes().GetEnumerator();
            while(enumerator.MoveNext()) 
                yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

If Box A held Boxes B and C, box B held boxes D and E, and box C held box F, the enumerable would come out A, B, D, E, C, F.

Comment: Your `foreach` effectively results in a return type of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Box>>` which does not match the declared return type. I don't believe this would compile in C#. In F# you could change the second `yield` into a `yield!` and it would work just fine.

Comment: You're exactly right. Quick edit to iterate through the IEnumerable returned by the child Box.